# How to define array type in C and making it a const pointer (not pointer to const)

Tags: c, arrays, typedef, c99

I know that I can define array types in C like the following:

```
typedef int array_t[123];
```

This however does not make a declaration

```
void someFunction(array_t myArray)
```

constant in the sense that

```
myArray=0;
```

is forbidden inside the function, but

```
myArray[0]=0;
```

is allowed.

Is there a way to achieve this? If I add a "const" in the type definition or the parameter declaration, I end up with the reverse behavior, where array elements are constant, but the array pointer itself is variable.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the array pointer".

Comment: Doing something like `array = xyz;` is kind of doing `3 = xyz;`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: The OP is talking specifically about array types used in the context of function parameter list. In that context they are immediately interpreted as pointers.

Comment: Using `typedef` to hide arrays is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely need have to have an `typedef`, use struct to to encapsulate it. Using `typedef` on arrays is not a good idea.

```
typedef struct {
    int arr[123];
} array_t;
```

And then you can do what Joachim Pileborg suggested with `const`:

```
void someFunction(array_t * const myArray)
{
    myArray->arr[0] = ...
```

Additional advantage to this approach is that you can also transmit other data with your object.

Comment: It's not the simple solution that I was hoping for (like putting a "const" into an unexpected place), but I guess there is no better way -> Accepted.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't see the point in defining that struct at all. The struct wrapper is sometimes used for making the array copyable. In this case there's no such request. So, if the objective is to pass a compile-time sized array without losing size information, then one can simply pass it as `void foo(int (*const a)[123])` or equivalently `void foo(array_t* const a)` (using the original typedef). No struct required.

Comment: @AndreyT Yes you are right in that this is not only solution. My perspective is that if you have array of specific size, it is likely a representation of some specific entity, opposed to just array of generic stuff. So in that case treating it as object makes more sense, and syntax is more straight-forward. But without knowing the actual use for this, it is hard to say what would be most optimal route.

Answer (score 5):

You can never assign to an array variable, no matter what. While arrays decays to pointers, as long as it hasn't decayed it's no pointer so you can't assign to it.

If you want to set all of the array to a specific value, use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset), or if you want to copy another array use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

---

After the edit. The important thing to remember here is that if you pass it as an argument, then it's passed as a pointer and not an array.

What you can do is to declare the argument as a constant pointer instead of a pointer to constants.

Like

```
void someFunction(int * const myArray);
```

Then you can still modify the elements, but you can't change the actual pointer.

Comment: Your solution does not use the typedef anymore. Without the typedef, it's trivial and I would not have asked the question. In my case, the typedef is required for other reasons.

Comment: @LPG Then unfortunately it's not really possible.

Answer (score 1):

C99 did introduce syntax for declaring constant pointer parameters through "array" syntax

```
void foo(int a[const 123]) /* same as `int *const a` */
{
  a = NULL; // ERROR
}
```

As you can see in the above example, `const` have to be placed inside the `[]`.

However, that `const` cannot be embedded into array type "in advance" by using a `typedef` declaration for an array type. It can only be used directly in function parameter list.

Comment: Very interesting and unexpected syntax. Unfortunately, I need the typedef (I do not want to lose the array's size information).

Comment: @LPG: Well, even when you use typedef-name for parameter declaration (as in your example) the parameter type still decays to pointer type. I.e. the parameter itself will lose the array size information anyway. Typedefing the array type does not prevent this from happening. I.e. `sizeof(myArray)` inside your function is size of a pointer, not size of the entire array.

Comment: @LPG Traditional and most flexible way is to use another parameter to pass array size information to function. Don't try to use `sizeof` tricks. Those will only cause headaches in the long run.

Comment: @LPG: Yes, `sizeof(array_t)` will give you the size of the array, but it has absolutely no connection to how you declare the function parameter. In your first comment, you said that this "unexpected" syntax does not work for you because you "don't want to lose array size information". But if you are planning to use `sizeof(array_t)` anyway, then the parameter declaration syntax makes no difference at all.

Comment: Alternatively, if the array size is fixed at compile time (and it apparently is, since you accepted struct-based solution) and you don't want to lose the array size information, then the best way to pass that parameter might be `void foo(int (*const a)[123])` or, equivalently, `void foo(array_t *const a)`, i.e. by using a pointer of pointer-to-array type. This is fairly equivalent to the struct solution, but without having to define a struct. In this case `sizeof *a` will produce the full array size. You will just have to remember to access your array as `(*a)[i]`.